# Flask App Timesout on when using Docker on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, flask, aws-lambda

I am attempting to deploy a Flask app on AWS Lambda by exposing it on API gateway. Judging by the Cloudwatch logs, it looks like my Flask app is being recreated everytime the endpoint is hit. When I hit the endpoint, the response I get back is `{"message": "Endpoint request timed out"}`

My `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
# start by pulling the python image
FROM python:3.9-slim

COPY . ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# install necessary gcc compiler
# RUN yum clean all
# RUN yum update -y
# RUN yum install gcc-c++.x86_64 -y
# RUN yum install python3-devel.x86_64 -y
# RUN yum install unixODBC.x86_64 -y
# RUN yum install unixODBC-devel.x86_64 -y

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev
RUN apt-get install -y gcc
RUN apt-get install -y g++

# Install the function's dependencies using file requirements.txt
# from your project folder.
RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"
EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

My `app.py looks like this:

```
def create_flask_app(config: dict):
    from flask import Flask
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app = register_app(app, config)
    return app


def register_app(app, config: dict):
    app.config.update(config)
    import views.index

    app.register_blueprint(views.index.routes)
    return app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_flask_app({
        # config stuff
    })
    app.run(threaded=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

My `views/index.py`

```
from flask import Blueprint

routes = Blueprint('index', __name__)


@routes.route('/', methods=["GET"])
def index():
    return "<h1>Hello World from Mill City 2!</h1>", 200
```

Cloudwatch logs look like this:

```
* Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
* Environment: production
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: off
* Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
* Running on http://169.254.76.1:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
START RequestId: 935b40fe-0705-4b10-8632-7dd825c569e0 Version: $LATEST
* Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
* Environment: production
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: off
* Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
* Running on http://169.254.76.1:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
END RequestId: 935b40fe-0705-4b10-8632-7dd825c569e0
REPORT RequestId: 935b40fe-0705-4b10-8632-7dd825c569e0  Duration: 30034.98 ms   Billed Duration: 30000 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 57 MB  
2022-05-24T19:58:02.465Z 935b40fe-0705-4b10-8632-7dd825c569e0 Task timed out after 30.03 seconds

* Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
* Environment: production
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: off
* Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
* Running on http://169.254.76.1:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
START RequestId: 26e96cca-40d7-429e-992e-265d1b54f5d5 Version: $LATEST
* Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
* Environment: production
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
```

Comment: What's the problem here? Your 30 second timeout? Increase it to any value that you need in your Lambda settings; do note it has a 15 minute max.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary increasing it to 5minute yields the same result. Also, should the flask app be restarting each time? I thought AWS keeps it up for you.

Thanks.

Comment: Lambdas are for quick invocations, normally an API, not for applications that may need a constant instance running. It looks like you're just running a Docker instance which then stays waiting for a connection? Using Lambdas require a serverless mindset shift, you can't just lift and shift unfortunately. Start from here :) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary thanks for the link. I was really trying to follow along with this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/deploying-python-flask-microservices-to-aws-using-open-source-tools/

I recognize that my docker file is a bit different but the CMD is the exact same as the example.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary i am an idiot, this link uses ECS. Thanks.

Comment: Not an idiot! No worries, yes ECS would keep it up & running.